# CAN Stack implementation on Rh850

Tags: c, embedded, can-bus

I am working on CAN stack and using RH850 controller, which is having 16 Rx buffers and 8 Tx buffers per channel. I have around 70-75 Rx frame and 30-35 Tx frames to handle. Is there any resource issue in implementing this many frames? Kindly reply your experience/thought on this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well yes, your program must be fast enough to handle all those frames and you'll likely need to store copies of all/some of the buffers in RAM... The question is too broad and vague really, without knowing the timing requirements and product purpose. It is not clear what's meant by "handling" those frames, everything would depend on how often they are sent. As always when designing CAN networks, you'll have to do bus load calculations. Also if this is an automotive application, there might be safety requirements to consider - node starvation or buffer overruns are usually unacceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Everything depends from your environment. Anyway you should avoid analyzing CAN message during interrupt handler directly from these hardware buffers because it takes too much time. I recommend you to check if DMA supports CAN messages transfers. If yes, you can have much larger space in RAM and don't be limited by hw buffers. The biggest advantage of this solution is that you don't need to analyze the frame immediately so you can focus on more critical tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the **filter mask** option in RH850 (It's there in most of the Micro support the CAN)..., You can consider it a primary feature, and this is there in all RH850 series... It's applicable only for Rx messages because not that useful for Tx messages...

How it works is, Using a filter mask register for each HW mailbox, you can configure which all messages can store in that specific mail box. In filter mask, you are normally selecting which all pits of the message ID are don't care when CAN HW check for the mailbox for the new message received.

But here one point you need to take care of is, if the second message came before the first message read out then you will/ can get a Data loss error. So to Identify which CAN message to be stored (club tougher) in the same mailbox you need to do the analysis of message periodicity and offset, and configure messages with maximum timing difference between each other in the same mailbox.

In RH850 all Rx buffers are linked to the same number of mailboxes, or you can consider each normal Rx mailbox does have buffer to store one message and for FIFO type you can store more number of instance of messages in the same mailbox...

Hope it's clear...